# using contextclick in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use ContextClick() method from selenium webdriver to right click on element and select the second option from context menu. this is my sample code here. when i execute this right click opetion doesnt happen on the element specified, no error message as well.
I'm using selenium 3.4, tried for both firefox and chrome driver.

Any help on this much appreciated..!

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com"); 
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("London");

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
action.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']"))).build().perform();
```

Comment: What exaclty wat may i know

Answer (score 0):

this is known issue of Firefox and selenium jar 3.2 and above

See this issue links:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/233
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3348

When I tried it throw the Exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: mouseMoveTo

I have tried this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:/software and tools/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver( );
 driver.get("http://google.com"); 
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("London");
 driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
 WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']"));
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(ele);
 action.contextClick(ele).build().perform();
```

Also I modified your code as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']")).click();
```

as this statement throw `nosuchelementexception` Exception as it is hiding, Try this code it works for me

Comment: Thanks @iamsankalp89, i'm able to right click on the element but when try to click the option from the context menu it hits enter. instead of selecting option from context menu this is what i'm doing  
  
 action.contextClick(ele).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();